# Visualization of K-Means Clustering of multiple columns

Tags: python, visualization, k-means

Dataset file : [google drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UuWMK1XH52mU4L6hoI1vhR8RVdF_fxgO/view?usp=sharing)

Hello Community , I need help regarding how to apply **KNN** clustering on this use case.

I have a dataset consisting `(27884 ROWS, 8933 Columns)`

Here's a little preview of a dataset

| user_iD | b1 | b2 | b3 | b4 | b5 | b6 | b7 | b8 | b9 | b10 | b11 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 7 | 2 | 3 | 8 | 0 | 4 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 5 |
| 2 | 7 | 8 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 6 | 5 | 9 | 10 | 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 5 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 0 | 6 |
| 4 | 1 | 7 | 2 | 3 | 8 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 6 | 0 | 4 |
| 5 | 0 | 4 | 7 | 0 | 6 | 1 | 5 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| 6 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 0 | 5 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 6 | 7 |

Here the column userid represents: **STUDENTS**
and columns b1-b11: They represent Book Chapters and the sequence of each student that which chapter he/she studied first then second then third and so on.  the 0 entry tells that the student did not study that particular chapter.

This is just a small preview of a big dataset.
There are a total of **27884** users and **8932** Chapters stated as **(b1--b8932)**

Here's the complete dataset shape information

[image]

I'm Applying KMEANS CLUSTERING.  How do I visualize all the clusters using all the columns

As I stated there are 27844 users & 8932 other columns
I have achieved by just using user_iD & b1 column only. How do I take all the columns at once?

What I have tried so far

```
#Build and train the model
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
model = KMeans(n_clusters=5)
model.fit(df3)

#See the predictions
model.labels_
model.cluster_centers_

#PLot the predictions against the original data set
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
#ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
plt.scatter(df3['user_iD'], df3['b1'],cmap='rainbow',
           linewidths=1, alpha=.7,
           edgecolor='k'
           )
plt.show()
```

This gives me clustering visualization based on a single column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Kmeans you have one more column in your dataset

```
df["kmeans_cluster"] = model.labels_
```

To visualize the data points, you have to select 2 or 3 axes (for 2D and 3D graphs). You can then use `kmeans_cluster` for points' colors and `user_iD` for points' labels.

Depending on your needs, you can use:

- b1 et b2 as axes : to see how these 2 books affect the Kmeans results
- First 2 or 3 PCA components (cf [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72171651/3063243) )
- The results of `t-sne` or `Umap` dimension reduction algorithms

Here is some code snippets you can use: [link1](https://plotly.com/python/t-sne-and-umap-projections/), [link2](https://github.com/gauss256/t-SNE/blob/master/t-SNE%20Explorations.ipynb)

Side note: you may want to remove `user_id` column before applying the Kmeans.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you cannot do it directly if you have more than 3 columns. However, you can apply a Principal Component Analysis to reduce the space in 2 columns and visualize this instead.

```
pca_num_components = 2

reduced_data = PCA(n_components=pca_num_components).fit_transform(df3.iloc[:,1:12])
results = pd.DataFrame(reduced_data,columns=['pca1','pca2'])

sns.scatterplot(x="pca1", y="pca2", hue=df3['clusters'], data=results)
plt.title('K-means Clustering with 2 dimensions')
plt.show()
```